# Ansible Multi data center deployment

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

My *dev* inventory file is:

```ini
[dev]
service1 ansible_host=dev1.com ansible_port=22 ansible_user=ubuntu
service2 ansible_host=dev1.com ansible_port=22 ansible_user=ubuntu
service3 ansible_host=dev1.com ansible_port=22 ansible_user=ubuntu
```

I execute below roles for service:

```yaml
roles:
- sync_code
- prep_local
- build
- shutdown_app
- setup_host
- start_app
```

I have  `serial: yes` so when I deploy any service, each role is executed sequentially.

For *prod*, there are 2 datacenters, DC1 and DC2; services are deployed in both datacenters, and multiple servers in each datacenter can host that particular service.

When I start deployment of service1 in *prod*, I want to pick 1 server from DC1 and 1 server from DC2, run all the roles sequentially, and then pick the next 1-1 servers from each datacenter.

What's the best way to organize the inventory file and how should I set the host's value in the playbook to achieve this?

Basically, on two hosts at the same time, run a bunch of code in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

**Symmetric groups**

Use the module [add_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html#ansible-builtin-add-host-module-add-a-host-and-alternatively-a-group-to-the-ansible-playbook-in-memory-inventory) and create dynamic inventory group. For example, given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[dc1]
node_1
node_2
node_3

[dc2]
node_4
node_5
node_6
```

The first play will create the inventory group *rolling_update*. The second play will use it

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: rolling_update
      loop: "{{ groups.dc1|zip(groups.dc2)|flatten }}"
      run_once: true
    
- hosts: rolling_update
  serial: 2
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [add_host] ******************************************************************************
changed: [node_1] => (item=node_1)
changed: [node_1] => (item=node_4)
changed: [node_1] => (item=node_2)
changed: [node_1] => (item=node_5)
changed: [node_1] => (item=node_3)
changed: [node_1] => (item=node_6)

PLAY [rolling_update] ************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [node_4] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_4
ok: [node_1] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_1

PLAY [rolling_update] ************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [node_2] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_2
ok: [node_5] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_5

PLAY [rolling_update] ************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [node_3] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_3
ok: [node_6] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_6
  ...
```

See:

- [Setting the batch size with serial](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#setting-the-batch-size-with-serial)
- [Selecting a strategy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#selecting-a-strategy)
- [Ordering execution based on inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#ordering-execution-based-on-inventory)

---

**Asymmetric groups**

If the groups are not symmetric, for example

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[dc1]
node_1
node_2
node_3

[dc2]
node_4
node_5
```

the filter [zip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest) won't exhaust the lists. The result will be (abridged)

```yaml
PLAY [rolling_update] ************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [node_1] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_1
ok: [node_4] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_4

PLAY [rolling_update] ************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [node_2] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_2
ok: [node_5] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_5
```

If you want to run the play for all hosts use the filter [zip_longest](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest)

```yaml
      loop: "{{ groups.dc1|zip_longest(groups.dc2)|flatten }}"
```

Then, the result will be (abridged)

```yaml
PLAY [rolling_update] ************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [node_1] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_1
ok: [node_4] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_4

PLAY [rolling_update] ************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [node_2] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_2
ok: [node_5] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_5

PLAY [rolling_update] ************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [node_3] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_3
```

---

**General solution**

Given the hosts

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[dc1]
node_1

[dc2]
node_4
node_5
node_6
```

the result will be (abridged)

```yaml
PLAY [rolling_update] ************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [node_1] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_1
ok: [node_4] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_4

PLAY [rolling_update] ************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [node_5] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_5
ok: [node_6] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_6
```

If you always want to run the play for only one host from each group create two dynamic inventory groups

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    ru1: "{{ groups.dc1|zip(groups.dc2)|flatten }}"
    idx: "{{ ru1|length - 1 }}"
    ru2: "{{ groups.dc1[idx|int:]|symmetric_difference(groups.dc2[idx|int:]) }}"

  tasks:

    - block:

        - debug:
            msg: |
              ru1: {{ ru1 }}
              ru2: {{ ru2 }}

        - add_host:
            name: "{{ item }}"
            groups: rolling_update1
          loop: "{{ ru1 }}"

        - add_host:
            name: "{{ item }}"
            groups: rolling_update2
          loop: "{{ ru2 }}"

      run_once: true
    
- hosts: rolling_update1
  serial: 2
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
    
- hosts: rolling_update2
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

Then, the result will be (abridged)

```yaml
PLAY [rolling_update1] ***********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [node_4] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_4
ok: [node_1] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_1

PLAY [rolling_update2] ***********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [node_5] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_5

PLAY [rolling_update2] ***********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [node_6] => 
  inventory_hostname: node_6
```

If you run this playbook on symmetric groups you'll see the warning

> [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: rolling_update2

[TODO: get rid of the warning]